# Display messagebox in dll library

Tags: c#, .net, dll, message

I am writing a dll library (for example for checking login details of a user) and I want to pop up a confirmation dialog or a informational dialog in the process, for example

`"Are you sure you want to continue? (Yes/No/Cancel)"`

for some reason. At present I am need this for an application in Winforms and I want to use same dll for my other webforms applications also. Can anyone guide how to achieve it? Need less to say I don't want to reference `System.Windows.Forms` or `System.Web`. Can any one give me some pointers? I am using .net 4.0

I don't want to for Publication/Subscription of events as I am not very familiar with cab architecture.

**EDIT**

I have a dll for creating database at runtime of an application. So my dll generally checks if the database already exists and is upto date or not, if it is then stop. But if it does not exist or not upto date, then I want to ask user if he want to update it now or afterwards. If user says now, update it and says afterwards continue to application. It is just an example and any relevant information on this is welcome.

Thanks.

Comment: Well, you can reference VisualBasic.Interop ... But I guess that won't satisfy you either, am I right?

Comment: You cannot possibly view a window in a non-window environment without using window-supporting libraries.

Comment: Well i think that's why we have `Confirm` for web

Comment: Yes, but how would you tell inside the DLL if you are in the web or not, and how would you wait on the return of a javascript client confirm() call inside a call into a DLL inside a webform project?

Comment: If you want `MessageBox` you need `System.Windows.Forms`.  If you want web controls, you need `System.Web`.  Why the aversion to referencing those?

Comment: You could raise an event or an exception. Event is the better way.

Comment: Be sure that the keys to the server room are easily accessible.  Having a DLL guess at the proper user interface is a lossy proposition.  Raise an event instead.

Comment: when I say web and winforms, I just want to say different platforms (like windows phone also), but will keep your idea in mind

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You really shouldn't. This does not belong in a library, but should be done in the application that uses this library instead.

Where a WinForms application might solve it by showing a `MessageBox`, a web application might perform the request without asking after a successful POST (since a POST usually shows the intent to modify a resource).

When for example your library is used for logging in, simply throw a `AuthenticationException`, so the client application (whether it's WinForms, web, or whatever) can catch that and display the appropriate message.

---

As for your edit:

> I have a dll for creating database at runtime of an application ...

Why not expose two methods like `IsDatabaseUpToDate()` and `UpdateDatabase()`? Then in the client, you can call the first method. If it returns false, you ask the user (be it with a MessageBox, an HTML form, a JavaScript Alert, a simple Yes button or a blinking tile) whether they want to update the database. If so, you call the `UpdateDatabase()` method and you're ready to go.

Comment: But what if the message need to be shown in the middle of the method? I want to do something after user clicks Yes/No/Cancel

Comment: @rapsalands then you should split that method up into multiple smaller methods, and let those questions be answered with the parameters used to call that method. Can you give exact examples of when you think you might need this?

Comment: trust me meanwhile I was trying and I did the same thing.

Comment: So is it possible? I wish someone would actually answer how to do this.

Comment: @JasonAxelson: Let your library expose a interface (with method `ShowPopup`) and your form implement that interface. Implementation of `ShowPopup` should have `MessageBox.Show`. Then call `ShowPopup` from library and you done. If still not clear......let me know

Answer (score 0):

To accomplish this you need to right click on the project and select "Add Reference", then select the ".NET" tab and click "System.Windows.Forms". Then this should work inside the .dll:

```
System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show("Hello World!");
```

Of course this is a bad idea for the original poster (as covered by CodeCaster).

Comment: never....how can you add windows form reference to a library. This will make your library incompatible with other platforms like webforms